# How to produce one output PCollection from multiple inputs PCollections in google data flow pipelines?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm trying to produce a `PCollection<C>` (with elements from type C), from 2 inputs using a tranformer: one `PCollection<A>` (with elements from type A), and the second one a `PCollection<C>`.

Basically, the transformer takes in account the elements stored in the `PCollection<A>` and do some computation with the elements on `PCollection<C>` in a such way in the end it will produces as output a new PCollection with new elements.

So, is there any way to implement this scenario using either `PCollectionTuple`, or `ParDo` over `PCollectionTuple` to produce just only one output `PCollection`, or any other suggestions using the Google Dataflow SDK?

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of ways to join PCollections in Dataflow.  For your case, where each element in the `PCollection<C>` needs to access potentially multiple elements in the `PCollection<A>`, you can use a side input.  See the [View](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/View.java) transform for more information.

For example, assuming pCollectionA is small:

```
PCollectionView<List<A>> view = View.asList(pCollectionA);
PCollection<C> output = pCollectionC.apply(ParDo.withSideInputs(view).of(
  new DoFn<C,C>() {
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) { 
      c.output(...combine c.element() and c.sideInput(view)...);
    }
  });
```

If you only need to access parts of pCollectionA for each element, you can use View.asMultimap instead, which will allow point lookups in pCollectionA

Comment: thanks a lot @danielm. In my case the `PCollection<A>` has just one element as it's a result from a previous CombineFn. So, yes `PCollection<A>` is small in this case.

Comment: @danieml, so just some more doubts: in this case, for each `PCollection<C>` distributed across the servers, do I have the warranty the same and whole `PCollection<A>` will be available in this case as a `List` of type A when the DoFn function is executed in parallel? Is it made copies of the `PCollection<A>`for each distributed server?